# Updating one Generic List<T> with Another Via Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm able to achieve this in a for-each loop. I'd like to achieve this via  linq query to be as concise as possible.
Here is my foreach sample :

```
 foreach (var item in List2)
 {
     List1.Where(m => m.id == item.id).FirstOrDefault().Selected = item.Selected;
 }
```

So essentially , I'd like to  return an updated list (List2)

Comment: How does `List1` and `List2` look like?

Comment: Are there any elements in List1 which have the same `id`? That is, is the `id` of every element different?

Comment: And why do you wat to do this with linq? Do not use linq to mutate data, if you want a one liner (for reasons of your own) then use `List.ForEach`.

Comment: Don't try to write one liners for no reason. 
Also, if both lists are large, it also might be better to create a lookup out of list1.

Comment: [Don't use `List.ForEach`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: List1 and list 2 are the same in structure but they differ by the `Selected` property .@MichaC good point , however the data set here is not going to be large

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the `Selected` properties of the items from one list to another. I think your foreach loop is too complicated, a cleaner foreach should be like this:

```
foreach (var item in List1)
{
    item.Selected = List2.First(m => m.id == item.id).Selected;
}
```

Although you may write one-liner using `List.ForEach` like below, but I prefer using `foreach`.

```
List1.ForEach(item => item.Selected = List2.First(m => m.id == item.id).Selected);
```

Comment: This is as short as it gets. I've gotten to like the join form because of the reason I added in my answer and because it is easier to set more properties.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do things like that by joining the lists.

```
var joined = from i1 in list1
             join i2 in list2 on i1.id = i2.id
             select new { i1, i2 };
joined.ToList().Foreach(x => x.i1.Selected = x.i2.Selected);
```

This is probably the most *succinct* way to do it. A `foreach` loop will *perform* better though. It also prevents null reference exceptions, or ways to deal with them, because it automatically skips items that have no counterpart in `list2`.

Note that this works because `list1` is an in-memory list, which I infer from your example. If `list1` is an `IEnumerable` it will be repopulated when it's accessed later on in the code, erasing the previous changes.

Comment: The `ToList().ForEach` is wasteful -- you generate an in-memory list for no reason. Using a `foreach` loop is a lot cheaper

Comment: @canton7 Yes, I know, I was still editing my answer. OP asked for a concise solution, which isn't always the best one.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with a combination of `Where()` and `ForEach()` method.

```
List1.Where(x => List2.Where(y=> y.id == x.id).ToList().Count > 0).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Selected = List2.FirstOrDefault(y => x.id == y.id).Selected)
```

and if you don't want to use `ForEach()`, you can use this with `Select()`:

```cs
List1 = List1.Where(x => List2.Where(y=> y.id == x.id).ToList().Count > 0).ToList().Select(x => {x.Value = List2.FirstOrDefault(y => x.id == y.id).Value; return x;}).Concat(List1.Where(x => List2.Where(y=> y.id == x.id).ToList().Count == 0)).ToList();
```

However, it's too long in my opinion

**Update: I fixed the problems Thanks to @canton7**

Comment: @canton7, I fixed it

Comment: Still pretty sure it does something different. OP's code sets the `Selected` property on specific elements. Yours doesn't set this property.

Comment: @canton7, Thanks for useful comment's. I suppose I fixed that too